# How do I rename or edit the name of my saves?

Tags: xcom-2

I'd like to rename one of my saves in order to better understand what missions I had just completed and how far along in the story I was at that save's time.  However, I can't find anyway to either rewrite the name, edit the name, or simply overwrite with a new name.

I've tried using Load Save and Save, and neither provide the option to rename and older save.

How can I rename older saves? How do I rename any saved game?

Comment: Have you tried looking into the games files? Everything is pretty well organised as far as I've seen, so you should be able to find them easy enough.

Comment: you could load the game, then resave with a new name and delete the one you just loaded

Comment: That's the workaround I'm doing, but I'd rather just rename since that's much simpler to do

Comment: @Gilsham I was going to put that in as an answer until I saw your comment. You want to do it? Will get at least one upvote.

Comment: @DCShannon ok, adding now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could load the save game you want to name, then resave with a the new name and delete the one you just loaded